Embedded pdf in revealjs doesn't work when sharing
I'm trying to use the embedpdf Quarto extension to show pdfs inside a revealjs presentation. This works fine when I run the presentation on my own, but when I share it the embedded pdf doesn't work anymore and returns in a download url which also doesn't work. Here is a reproducible example of first without embed-resources: true in yaml:
---
title: "Embed pdf"
format: revealjs
---

## Example slide

{{< pdf https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf width=100% height=800 >}}

Output:

Using the embed-resources: true to share presentations:
---
title: "Embed pdf"
format: 
  revealjs:
    embed-resources: true
---

## Example slide

{{< pdf https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf width=100% height=800 >}}

Output:

As you can see it doesn't work anymore. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to share a revealjs presentation including embedded pdf objects?
Please note: The output of the second example is the output when you have shared the presentation to someone for example by mail.

I am unable to reproduce this issue on my end. I am running quarto version 1.4.553. Maybe updating will fix the issue?

Hi @JoshAllen, Thank you for your comment. Did you also try to share the second example to someone? For example by mail. Do you understand what I mean?

I tried sharing it via email with myself, which worked. I also added it to my website here. Which both worked
